# ¿Cómo deshabilitar las notificaciones http de segundo plano en NativeScript?

Tags: javascript, npm, nativescript

Soy nuevo en cuanto a las aplicaciones con NativeScript. Intento desarrollar una app que envie imágenes a un servidor web. Puedo enviar y recibir archivos sin problemas. Pero me he dado cuenta que cuando se termina cada transferencia Android muestra una notificación y si envío muchos archivos, las notificaciones se vuelven irritantes.

¿Alguien me puede ayudar a corregir esto?

Comment: usted es una persona con suerte esto es stackoverflow en español solo tendra que [edit] su pregunta a su idioma, quizas le ayude leer [ask] para formular su pregunta y [tour] para entender mejor el sitio, bienvenido a stackoverflow. Saludos

Comment: tambien seria bueno que pongas el codigo y que expliques mejor por que preguntas por uploads en android pero la pregunta esta etiquetada como javascript y npm. Quiza debas editar y corregir las etiquetas o explicar un poco mejor el escenario. Salu2.-